# How to write data in parquet format

Tags: java, parquet

I have some data in my ArrayList> can we write this data  in parquet file or not, if yes then how,please recommend and Java program,thanks in advance.

Please Note I am not using any Spark,Kafka...

Answer (score 6):

Previous link mostly contains Avro schema examples (I'm wondering, why people don't read the question before an answer). I did not manage to find any reliable examples so far. What you can use is this [schema file](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/parquet/example/Paper.java) and [this article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-convert-existing-data-into-parquet/). Also, there is a [repo with more](https://github.com/FelixNeutatz/parquet-flinktacular) examples.

Answer (score 1):

Have you googled it?

Try [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter), for example.

Comment: hi,I have gone though this and from the example 7,source code I want to implement similar thing (http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=pbase-master/hbase-server/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/pbase/util/GenerateParquetFile.java) ,

Comment: but after adding all dependencies code not working , I am getting issue near  ParquetWriter<Group> writer = new ParquetWriter<Group>(initFile(fileName),new GoupWriteSupport(metas),CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY, 1024,1024,512,true,false,ParquetProperties.WriterVersion.PARQUET_1_0,conf); 
 the The constructor GroupWriteSupport(Map<String,String>) is undefined, please can you help on this

Comment: It is not undefined. The constructor is:  GroupWriteSupport(MessageType schema, Map<String, String> extraMetaData). Add schema